# ReactJS project that outputs components to be used in non-ReactJS sites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to introduce ReactJS components into a non-ReactJS site. I have created a project that bundles my components and minifies them ([based on this](https://medium.com/@sevenleaps/using-react-components-in-non-react-websites-12fb7d71b63f)).

I have this functionality working but it means that my build folder is full of single JS files. I would like to define some sort of folder structure within it, without having to define an entry for each component.

Below are my attempts at writing my Webpack.config.js file

Attempt 1:

```
entry: {
    ComponentOne : './src/components/export/ComponentOne/control/ComponentOne.jsx',
    ComponentTwo : './src/components/export/ComponentTwo/control/ComponentTwo.jsx',
},

output: {
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
},
```

This attempt means I will have to add an entry for every component I want to export and my build folder will just become full of files and I'd prefer to have some sort of file structure in place.

Attempt 2:

```
entry: {
    '/ComponentOne/ComponentOne' : './src/components/export/ComponentOne/control/ComponentOne.jsx',
    '/ComponentTwo/ComponentTwo' : './src/components/export/ComponentTwo/control/ComponentTwo.jsx'
}, 

output: {
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
},
```

This attempt will help my structure the files, but again I will have define an entry for each component, and this then causes an error in my exported JS file as the variable name then becomes:

```
var /ComponentOne/ComponentOne =
```

Attempt 3:

```
entry: glob_entries(path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/export/**/control/*.jsx')),

output: {
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
},
```

Using 'webpack-glob-entries' solves my issue of not having to define each entry but I am left with the same problem of the build file just being full of single JS files with no file structure.

I'd like my build file to keep the file structure of the components but still be able to use something similar to 'webpack-glob-entries' to not have to define each entry.

Comment: why are you using a bundler if you don't want it to bundle?

Comment: @Hamms I'm new to webpack and I may well be doing this wrong, I'm trying to contain the React component within a function to be used from javascript. If you can point me to an alternative method I'd be grateful

Comment: You almost certainly want to use a tool other than webpack to achieve what you're trying to do, but it's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do. You mention your goal is to bundle and minify your components, but I don't think you actually want to bundle them (since bundling is the act of combining them all into a single entry point). Do you perhaps mean transpile and minify?

Comment: Or do you literally just want to minify?

Comment: So I have 1 file which is the react component as normal, another file which renders that react component within a function. I then want to (bundle/transpile/minify?) this file. I will then reference this file in a separate website to render the componet from the javascript function."https://medium.com/@sevenleaps/using-react-components-in-non-react-websites-12fb7d71b63f like this but I will have many different components

Comment: Is your goal to use multiple of these components on the same website? You should be aware that by following this approach, you will be including all the dependencies for each component in each generated file. This means if you have three of these components on a page, you'll actually be including the entire react and react-dom suites three times.

Comment: Yes I understand I will have react and react-dom multiple times. I have another site which I want to recreate in react but it will be time consuming to replicate, so I want to write the new components in react, until I can completely change over. It is likely to only be one if any component per page so I think it'll be fine.

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to write your own version of [webpack-glob-entries](https://github.com/aurimasniekis/webpack-glob-entries/blob/master/index.js) that uses the full desired destination as the key (rather than `path.basename`), and to use a `libraryTarget` other than `var`